# Get if match on select clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables:

Communication table

```
+--------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------+
| ComKey |               ComGuid                | ComTypeKey | Address |
+--------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------+
|      1 | E2313033-8C00-45ED-BC1C-A6A055FDFADD |          1 | 66258456|
|      2 | 244127E6-1CAC-4BBF-BC34-EE8C4B48320B |          3 | test2   |
|      3 | E2313033-8C00-45ED-BC1C-A6A055FDFADD |          6 | test3   |
|      4 | 89CB8D22-339D-4678-880B-9A8C7CD61B85 |          8 | test4   |
|      5 | B38B93C3-1B89-42D8-9DCB-E280412FE501 |          9 | test5   |
|      6 | E2313033-8C00-45ED-BC1C-A6A055FDFADD |          2 | test6   |
|      7 | 32E0C750-7587-46AF-BCD8-669760092666 |          1 | test7   |
|      8 | FC88708A-77C6-481A-B0CF-45DD5DFD840E |          1 | test8   |
|      9 | E8391A84-9C27-418E-BF94-835AAC35E0DD |         11 | test9   |
|     10 | E8391A84-9C27-418E-BF94-835AAC35E0DD |          1 | test10  |
|     11 | 6C72571E-37A9-4418-8959-A0B38BBD3203 |          1 | test11  |
+--------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------+
```

ComType table

```
+------------+-------------------+
| ComTypeKey |    DeviceType     |
+------------+-------------------+
|          1 | Business Phone    |
|          2 | Business Fax      |
|          3 | Business Cell     |
|          4 | Business Email    |
|          5 | Business Web Site |
|          6 | Home Phone        |
|          7 | Home Fax          |
|          8 | Personal Cell     |
|          9 | Job Site Phone    |
|         10 | Job Site Fax      |
|         11 | Personal Email    |
|         12 | Personal Web Site |
+------------+-------------------+
```

Contact table

```
+------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+-------+
| ContactKey |             ContactGuid              |   Phone   | Email |
+------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+-------+
|          1 | E2313033-8C00-45ED-BC1C-A6A055FDFADD | 66258456  | NULL  |
+------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+-------+
```

Relation:

```
[Communication] AS [c]
                     INNER JOIN [ComType] AS [ct] ON [ct].[ComTypeKey] = [c].[ComTypeKey]
                     INNER JOIN [Contact] AS [con] ON [c].[ComGuid] = [con].[ContactGuid]
```

Problem:

I have a select clause where I use `CASE` statement like:

```
SELECT

                 IIF(CASE
                        WHEN [c].[ComTypeKey] = 1
                            OR [c].[ComTypeKey] = 3
                            OR [c].[ComTypeKey] = 6
                            OR [c].[ComTypeKey] = 8
                            OR [c].[ComTypeKey] = 9
                        THEN [con].[Phone]
                        WHEN [c].[ComTypeKey] = 4
                            OR [c].[ComTypeKey] = 11
                        THEN [con].[Email]
                    END IS NULL , 'No' , 'Yes') AS [IsPrincipal]
                 FROM [Communication] AS [c]
                     INNER JOIN [ComType] AS [ct] ON [ct].[ComTypeKey] = [c].[ComTypeKey]
                     INNER JOIN [Contact] AS [con] ON [c].[ComGuid] = [con].[ContactGuid]
```

As you can see I want values `Yes` or `No` depending if value is null and only apply with that ComType keys, at first instance it return info like I want, but my problem is I.E:

If Contact table has a `Phone` or `Email` value it always match with `Address` value of Communication table

In this case contact `E2313033-8C00-45ED-BC1C-A6A055FDFADD` has ComTypeKey `1,3 and 6` but only column Address of Communication table match with Phone value so `ComKey =  1` is the one I want to get `Yes` value because it match and others should be `No`

In this case I get 3 Yes because I don't know how to relate that values.

Comment: One of the problems is that the column names are confusing: `Communication.ComGuid` appears to actually be the `ContactGuid`. Why are they of different names? You also need to normalize the data. Why do you have the phone number in both the Communication and the Contact tables? I think you need to either have a `WHERE con.ContactKey = ct.ComTypeKey` or something similar to select only the `ComTypeKey` you want. Regardless, cleaning up your data model will greatly simplify your efforts.

Comment: Relationship is because old school programmer do that long time ago thats why differences between name. I have phone number in both tables because that communication table is used with other tables so I need to have phone and email for that specific contact. So that’s why I’m trying that @daShier

Comment: The idea of a relational database is that you can select the phone number and email from your `communications` table when you need it with a simple `JOIN`. By having the phone and email in two places it is both redundant  and requires multiple tables to be updated or else there can be errors (what if the `phone` in the `Contact` table doesn't match the `address` in the `communications` table`? Which one is assumed to be correct?

Comment: Select returns multiple result set, so for email should return yes or no depending if its null or not and Im sure every register match correctly, and I separate email and phone because there are other communication types that I dont want to involve in my select thats why I use case @daShier

Comment: Aside: `... when c.ComTypeKey in ( 1, 3, 6, 8, 9 ) then con.Phone ...` is easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this answers your question, you can decide:

```
select [con].[ContactGuid], c.[Address]
from [Contact] as [con]
INNER JOIN [Communication] AS [c] ON [c].[ComGuid] = [con].[ContactGuid]
WHERE (([c].[ComTypeKey] = 1 OR [c].[ComTypeKey] = 3 OR [c].[ComTypeKey] = 6 OR [c].[ComTypeKey] = 8 OR [c].[ComTypeKey] = 9)
AND con.[Phone] = c.[Address])

union all

select [con].[ContactGuid], c.[Address]
from [Contact] as [con]
INNER JOIN [Communication] AS [c] ON [c].[ComGuid] = [con].[ContactGuid]
WHERE (([c].[ComTypeKey] = 4 OR [c].[ComTypeKey] = 11) AND con.[Email] = c.[Address])
```